# How to migrate from Exchange service to Graph API to retrieve/sending emails

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have several console applications which using common project named as "Email provider" to get and send emails. I have to do migration of my Email Provider to do this functionality using Graph API. what could be the best way to achieve this with minimal efforts on all the console application. below is the connection and method I used. Please help.

```
public ExchangeEngine(string ServiceUrl, string MailboxName, string UserName, string Password,string Domain)
{
    service.Url = new Uri(ServiceUrl);
    service.TraceEnabled = false;
    service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password, Domain);
    service.AutodiscoverUrl(MailboxName, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
    mailBox = new Mailbox(MailboxName);
}
```

is it possible to make the connection through Graph API and get all the messages and convert them into "EmailMessage" object ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at using the Graph SDK eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

where you have

```
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password, Domain);
```

you will need to migrate this to use oAuth if its unattended code then look at using the client credentials flow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

You need to make sure all the users are using Exchange Online/Office365 to use that Graph if you have onPrem mailboxes you will still need to use EWS for those mailboxes

[edit based on comment]

If your going to be using both EWS and Graph in the same code base you want to move away from using EmailMessage or Graph Message Class directly in your upper business logic (otherwise you will need to duplicate a lot of code). Converting objects isn't a good idea and will generally just lead other issues. To abstract that away you want to create your own Message class (eg call it ProcessMessage etc) that should then contain all the properties (and methods) that you upper logic will need. Then you can either have a method that contains

> var messages = await graphClient.Me.Messages .Request() .Select("sender,subject") .GetAsync();

and returns a collection of your ProcessMessage objects for the Graph and similar with EWS you could have another method that returns the same collection of objects. That limits the duplication you have to do in your code to just the data provider (eg EWS or the Graph). A better way of doing this is using Interfaces and the Factory Pattern I have a simple example in https://github.com/gscales/MEC-Talk-2022/tree/main/DiscoveryLibraryEWSAndGraph

At the end of the day its about making your code more maintainable and easy to debug. For instance if you have a problem with Graph but EWS works okay then you just have to debug the Graph data provider code or vice versa. Or when you update in the future etc.

Comment: Thanks @Glen Scales. I have to use Graph APIs for this. so after getting messages from below code can you help me with the mapper I would need to create to convert it to older exiting EWS message object?

Comment: var messages = await graphClient.Me.Messages
 .Request()
 .Select("sender,subject")
 .GetAsync();

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to an old EWS object, you should just use the Graph Message object (if you don't have an OnPrem mailboxes) or use interfaces and abstract it away so it doesn't matter about the underlying data provider in your code.

Comment: Could you please explain with example?

Comment: Hi @Glen Scales, I have found code here https://github.com/ivfranji/GraphManagedApi  . Can you please help me with how to send email with large attachment using this code?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you use that library, while there is nothing wrong with the code or idea (IMO trying to copy the model EWS uses into the Graph is a bad idea), over the long term you will find it doesn't track the Graph API in terms of functionally or updates. I would suggest you use the Graph SDK which has code for that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-large-attachments?tabs=csharp and support if you need it.

Comment: Thanks @Glen Scales for the reply. This code is being used in many applications. so that is why I would need work around or mid level solution for this. help would be appreciated.

Comment: Create an Issue in GitHub for it, from what I see there is no support for that in the current code so its something the author would need to add (eg support for createUploadSession). But the best solution is move to the Graph SDK its the only way your going to have supportably in the future.